# the return value is IEnumerable and not IPaged

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I use ScriptServices to return IPaged<> result:

```
[WebService]
public IPaged<int> DoSomething() {
    ....
    ....
}
```

IPaged<> is:

```
public interface IPaged<T> : IEnumerable where T : class
{
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
    int PagesCount { get; }
    int TotalItemsCount { get; }
}
```

The Paged<> class that returned from DoSomething implements IPaged<> and therefore implements the `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`:

```
  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)Items).GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Whenever I call DoSomething from Javascript ajax, the script service engine returns IEnumerable instance and not IPaged so I get an array (the Items member from GetEnumerator() method).

How can I return IPaged<> and not IEnumerable<> from the script service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but it is *very* common for `IEnumerable[<T>]` (and also sometimes `IList[<T>]` to take priority over anything else, and jump into the "colllection of" branch (ignoring any properties defined on the "container").

As such, I expect your best bet is to not have `IPaged<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`.
This may mean having to change a few places to add `.Items`.

Another approach would to add a `ForJson()` extension method that returns something *similar* to `IPaged<T>`, but without implementing `IEnumerable[<T>]`.